# Firefox 45.0.1 doesn't play videos when run as a different user on ubuntu 15.10

Tags: firefox, 15.10, video, users

If something similar has already been posted somewhere: sorry about that; I am noobish...

I have a newly installed Ubuntu 15.10 and I'm trying to run firefox as a different user (lets call this user ff for short) with

```
gksu -u ff -w firefox
```

It works fine mostly, but will not play videos. For flash it freezes for a bit then tells me that flash crashed. For html5 (and pretty much everything else) it loads the first frame of the video but doesn't play it. The ff user is in the audio group.

What am I doing wrong?